# Datetime library in Python giving incorrect format for YYYY-MM-DD resulting in error after embedding in API call

Tags: python, datetime, format, sendgrid-api-v3

im new to python and trying to work with the Sendgrid api and the datetime library:

To try and pull email statistics my code is:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sendgrid.com")

payload = "{}"

headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer SG.***" }

conn.request("GET", "/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date=2020-01-14", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

This code works and I receive my desired output, however, I want to create this app such that it runs everyday through task scheduler and generates a report without nme manually changing the start date.

I tried:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
```

if i print(today) it gives me the exact format 20120-01-14 but if i directly call today it says

```
today
Out[37]: datetime.date(2020, 1, 14)
```

Below I tried to put "today" as my start date but got the error of format

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sendgrid.com")

payload = "{}"

headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer SG.***" }

conn.request("GET", "/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date=today", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

However, this gives me an error : {"errors":[{"message":"start_date is required and should be a YYYY-MM-DD formatted date"}]}

What can I do to put in the start_date in order for it to pickup the current date always without me manually changing it?

Comment: It should be `"/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date={}".format(str(today))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

And change this line from this:

```
conn.request("GET", "/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date=today", payload, headers)
```

to this:

```
conn.request("GET", "/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date={}".format(today), payload, headers)
```

And take a look over [python built-in date functions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html)

Comment: i want to add end_date but i want start date and end date as same day. where can i add it in the above code "end_date"

Comment: @hartvillezillow as an extra `GET` param, but you can use names: `"/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date={d}&end_date{d}".format(d=today)`

Comment: it does give me an output but not the one i desire. The issue is that when I dont set the start date and end date as today then in the output for some reason I also get information for 2020-01-16. I just want it for today that is 2020-01-15

Comment: @hartvillezillow well, that looks like a problem with API itself, you are maybe running into problems with timezone or something else. You should take a look over API's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date=today"
```

to

```
f"/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date={str(today)}"
```

or to this if you're using Python prior to 3.6

```
"/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date={}".format(str(today))
```

which is

> '2020-01-14'

And it'll work!

Comment: same error {"errors":[{"message":"start_date is required and should be a YYYY-MM-DD formatted date"}]}

Comment: @hartvillezillow what is the output of `str(today)` for you?

Comment: 2020-01-14 is the output